# Playscape Publishing Kit. failed run zipalign

Tags: unity-game-engine, playscape

Unable to build the project with Playscape Publishing Kit v1.11 on a Mac.

**An error occured while applying post-build logic: failed run zipalign**

Log:

AndroidSDKTools:

```
    root          : /Users/zombie/Documents/android-sdk-macosx
    tools         : /Users/zombie/Documents/android-sdk-macosx/tools
    platform-tools: /Users/zombie/Documents/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools
    build-tools   : /Users/zombie/Documents/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/22.0.1

    adb      : /Users/zombie/Documents/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/adb
    aapt     : /Users/zombie/Documents/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt
    zipalign : /Users/zombie/Documents/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/22.0.1/zipalign

AndroidJavaTools:
    java     : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java

Refresh: detecting if any assets need to be imported or removed ... Refresh: elapses 0.030350 seconds

----- Total AssetImport time: 0.024006s, AssetImport time: 0.000000s, Asset hashing: 0.000000s [0 B, 0.000000 mb/s]

Updating ProjectSettings/QualitySettings.asset - GUID: 00000000000000009000000000000000...
 done. [Time: 4.079194 ms] 

----- Total AssetImport time: 0.038209s, AssetImport time: 0.017489s, Asset hashing: 0.000000s [0 B, 0.000000 mb/s]

Platform assembly: /Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/Frameworks/Mono/lib/mono/2.0/I18N.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: /Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/Frameworks/Mono/lib/mono/2.0/I18N.West.dll (this message is harmless)
dex2jar /var/folders/nl/rrrmq6m95fd_5ttjk3bnpbth0000gn/T/qixm4qhi.8zq./classes.dex -> /var/folders/nl/rrrmq6m95fd_5ttjk3bnpbth0000gn/T/9tmxy7h8.du6.jar
Zip alignment utility
Copyright (C) 2009 The Android Open Source Project

Usage: zipalign [-f] [-v] <align> infile.zip outfile.zip
       zipalign -c [-v] <align> infile.zip

  <align>: alignment in bytes, e.g. '4' provides 32-bit alignment
  -c: check alignment only (does not modify file)
  -f: overwrite existing outfile.zip
  -v: verbose output
[PS-Warn] process failed with error 
UnityEngine.Debug:Internal_Log(Int32, String, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning(Object)
Playscape.Internal.L:W(String, Object[]) (at Assets/Plugins/Playscape/Internal/L.cs:43)
```

Comment: Vlad, Can you provide the arguments with which zipalign was called?

Comment: Can you please update which game are working on and if you still have this issue?